# Asymptotics for rapidly-oscillating integral with no stationary point of the phase

Tags: definite-integrals, asymptotics

I would like to establish the asymptotic behaviour of the following integral:
$$
I(r) = \int_0^\infty dq  \frac{q}{\sqrt{m^2 + q^2}} e^{-\sigma q^2 /2} \sin (q r)
$$
for $r \to + \infty$, with $m\geq 0$ and $\sigma >0$ real parameters. I know that $\lim_{r \to \infty} I(r) =0$, but I would like to know how it goes there. For example, in the $m=0$ case the integral can be performed exactly (it's the sum of two Gaussian integrals with complex coefficients), and the result is:
$$
I(r) \xrightarrow[m\to 0]{} \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2 \sigma }} \text{erfi}\left(\frac{r}{\sqrt{2\sigma }}\right) e^{-\frac{r^2}{2 \sigma }}
= \frac 1 r + \mathcal{O}\left( e^{-\frac{r^2}{2 \sigma }} \right) .
$$
I'm not sure how to go about the $m>0$ case. The sine function obviously can be written as a sum of two complex exponentials, and if I want I can also repack everything into a single integral from $q = -\infty$ to $q= + \infty$ with a single exponential:
$$
I(r) = \frac{1}{2i} \int_{-\infty}^\infty dq  \frac{q}{\sqrt{m^2 + q^2}} e^{-\sigma q^2 /2} e^{iq r} ,
$$
but I can't use the stationary phase approximation as it is, because the function $q$ in the exponent has no stationary points. I can transform for example $q = x^3$  and then $x=0$ is a stationary point, and I can expand the square root in Maclaurin series $\frac{1}{\sqrt{m^2+x^6}}\sim \frac{1}{m}-\frac{x^6}{2 m^3} + \dots$, and I can integrate separately each term, but what I get is that each term results in a $e^{-\frac{r^2}{2 \sigma }}$ factor multiplied by increasing powers of $r$, which means my expansion is not giving me the dominant behaviour for $I(r)$.

Thinking about the problem in the complex plane, I see that the oscillating parts $e^{\pm i q r}$ have their steepest descent directions on the imaginary axis of $q$, but the integrand $ \frac{q}{\sqrt{m^2 + q^2}} e^{-\sigma q^2 /2} $ converges to zero as $|q| \to \infty$ only in the butterfly-shaped region $|Im(q)|<|Re(q)|$, which does not include the imaginary axis. Moreover the square root at the denominator gives two poles at $q =\pm im$, from which two branch cuts have to depart and go to infinity. I don't see a deformation of the path of the positive real axis that allows me to go along the steepest-descent path and exploit the fact that $r$ is large.

This is as far as I got in the analysis of this problem, any suggestion on the best way to go about this?

Thanks everyone and best regards.

Comment: Riemann-Lebesgue lemma.

Comment: Yes the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma states that $I(r)$ vanishes as $r \to \infty$, but I need to find out how fast it does so, i.e. an asymptotic expansion.

Comment: Sorry, this was not working. I was thinking about the proof of the lemma but integration by parts takes nowhere.

Comment: Yes I see what you were trying to do... I can use integration by parts to show that the $m=0$ case gives a $1/r$ dominant term, but in the $m>0$case no matter how many times I integrate by part, each term cancels out. This, I think, has to do with the fact that the integrand, when written as in my third equation integrated over $(-\infty,\infty)$, is a $C^\infty $ function when $m>0$, while in the limit $m\to0$ it's not continuous in $0$ (it tends to the sign function times the Gaussian).

Comment: I'm saying this because from what  I gathered around the internet, it seems that the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma implies that the large-frequency limit of the Fourier transform of a function depends on its degree of smoothness, and an infinitely differentiable function will not go to zero like any polynomial of $r^{-1}$. I suppose it will go to zero like some exponential, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Comment: @Spinoro: yes, an infinitely differentiable function will go to zero faster than any power (i.e. usually exponentially). You can proof it with Riemann-Lebesgue and integration by parts (as you have noticed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $m > 0$ and $\sigma > 0$ are constant. The critical point of $-\sigma^2 q^2/2 + i r q$ is $q_0 = i r/\sigma$. If the non-exponential part didn't have a branch cut, the steepest descent contour would go through $q_0$ parallel to the real axis. But the contour for $I(r)$ has to be augmented with the segments from $q_0$ to the branch point $q_b = i m$ on both sides of the branch cut. The main contribution to the integral comes from a small neighborhood of $q_b$ and can be estimated by applying Laplace's method.

Taking $q = q_b + i \xi$ and expanding the exponential and non-exponential parts of the integrand around $\xi = 0$, we obtain
$$I(r) = \frac 1 2 \,\operatorname{Im} \int_{-\infty}^\infty
 \frac q {\sqrt {q^2 + m^2}} e^{-\sigma q^2/2 + i r q} dq \sim
e^{m (m \sigma/2 - r)}
 \int_0^\infty \sqrt {\frac m {2 \xi}} \,e^{(m \sigma - r) \xi} d\xi \sim \\
e^{m (m \sigma/2 - r)} \sqrt {\frac {\pi m} {2 r}},
\quad r \to \infty.$$

Comment: Ok guys I checked with some simple numerics the case $m=10$, $\sigma=1$. What I see is that for small $r$'s the Gaussian-like function $\frac{\sqrt{2 \pi } r e^{-\frac{r^2}{2 \sigma }}}{2 \sigma ^{3/2}}$ describes very well the data, but as soon as $\sqrt{\frac{\pi  m}{2 r}} e^{m \left(\frac{m \sigma }{2}-r\right)}$ becomes larger than it, $I(r)$ is described extremely well by $\sqrt{\frac{\pi  m}{2 r}} e^{m \left(\frac{m \sigma }{2}-r\right)}$. Here's the plot in log-log coordinates: [link](https://ibb.co/84YJLm3)

Comment: All of this is of course consistent with Maxim's result: the integral is well approximated by the sum of the Gaussian-like term and the exponential-like term, and the latter takes over when $r$ is sufficiently large.